# Iterate over indices of a list automatically

Tags: python, loops, csv, nested

I created code that allows me to create a csv file based on data.

```
import csv
with open('GoodContigs.csv','wb') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter = ',')
    l = [final_positions,final_contigs,actual_contigs,mismatches]
    l = zip(*l)
    data = [['Positions in Genome', 'Contigs', 'References', 'Mismatches'],
            l[0],
            l[1],
            l[2]]
    a.writerows(data)
```

In this example,

```
l = [(2, 'GAAACCG', 'GAACGA', 3), (4, 'TATG', 'TTTT', 2), (5, 'AATA', 'AAGT', 1)]
```

Therefore, `len(l)` is equal to 3.  Because of this, I need to manually write `l[0]`, `l[1]`, and `l[2]` in the above code.  The problem is that sometimes, the length of `l` will vary so I need to create a code that will automatically place these indices in for me.  I was thinking of replacing `l[0]`, `l[1]`, and `l[2]` in `data` by something like:

```
data = [['Positions in Genome', 'Contigs', 'References', 'Mismatches'],
        [l[s] for s in range(len(l))]]
```

But this doesn't work.  Instead of getting this.

[image: expected result]

I get this.

[image: actual result]

Any ideas?

Comment: something like: `data.extend(l)`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @darshvader I'm getting a syntax error.  I tried to solve this by putting 'l[s] for s in range(len(l))' in square brackets, but when I do this, my output csv file is weird since it groups the elements in my list together in one cell instead of separating them into separate rows.

Comment: On reasonably up-to-date python versions you can do `data = [['Positions in Genome', 'Contigs', 'References', 'Mismatches'], *l]`

Comment: @PaulPanzer This gives me an invalid syntax error

Comment: IMHO your problem is not as complicated as you make it by trying to write both header and data in one command. The length of `l` varies (if i assume correct) because the number of rows varies, not the number of columns. In other words, `zip(*l)` might have varying lengths, but every element of it has four subelements, right? So why don't you just write your header line and afterwards the list of data lines...

Comment: Well, you can also do `data = [['Positions in Genome', 'Contigs', 'References', 'Mismatches']] + l`. That should work on about any python version. Doesn't answer your headline question, though.

Comment: @SpghttCd You are right.  The length of L varies and every element in the list has four subelements. The problem is that I need the data in each list to be a column in the csv file, not a row.  *Refer to two images above* Maybe, I am not understanding exactly what you mean.  Would you happen to have any code?

Comment: @SpghttCd If I write afterwards the list of data lines, I would still have to manually write in a.writerows(l[0]), a.writerows(l[1]) anda.writerows(l[2]).  I need this to be done automatically by code.  Would the lambda function work here?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Please see the edited post.  I tried just adding the 'L' and that is what I got as my table, but I need the first image I posted.

Comment: @Thomas look carefully at the placement of the brackets in your example vs Paul's

Comment: @HenryWoody Thank you for pointing this out.  The code works now!